# Extra Pixels on HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to place my text on a certain part of the web page but when I change `left: 0px;` to `left: 130px;`it creates pixels that results in a horizontal bar appearing. Any idea on how can I fix this?

**CSS**

```
.main4{
text-align: left;
left: 0px;
line-height: 70px;
margin-top: -30px;
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
width: 98.7%;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 18px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main4">
<h1>Upon Doctor's advice</h1>
<h1>Upon advice by family, friends, relatives, another previous patient</h1>
<h1>Recommended by hospital employee</h1>
<h1>Employee's hospital privilege</h1>
<h1>Reputation as the center of best doctors</h1>
<h1>Recommended for good nursing care</h1>
<h1>Others (Please specify): </h1>
</div>
```

`left: 130px;`

[image]

`left: 0px;`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `width: 98.7%;`

```css
.main4{
text-align: left;
left: 130px;
line-height: 70px;
margin-top: -30px;
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 18px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main4">
<h1>Upon Doctor's advice</h1>
<h1>Upon advice by family, friends, relatives, another previous patient</h1>
<h1>Recommended by hospital employee</h1>
<h1>Employee's hospital privilege</h1>
<h1>Reputation as the center of best doctors</h1>
<h1>Recommended for good nursing care</h1>
<h1>Others (Please specify): </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal bar is caused by content going beyond the width of its parent. Here you've moved `.main4` 130px to the right, that will have pushed it outside the width of its parent. You need to (a) probably use padding, not position absolute, or (b) decrease the width of `.main4` until this doesn't happen.

Comment: I used width:90% to decrease the width and the horizontal bar was gone. Thank you so much!
+1 to you